# Postgresql commited data not visible

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I noticed weird behavior in my application. It looks like commited data is not visible right after commit. Algorithm looks like this :

```
connection1 - insert into table row with id = 5
connection1 - commit, close
connection2 - open
connection2 - select from table row with id = 5 (no results)
connection2 - insert into table row with id = 5 (PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION, result is in db)
```

If select on connection2 returns no results then i do insert, otherwise it is update.
Server has many databases (~200), it looks like commit is done but changes are in DB later. I use java and jdbc. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If the current transaction of connection2 was started before the transaction of connection1 was committed, it will not be able to see the changes

Comment: Connection2 is opened after connection1 commits.

Comment: Is it really a new fresh connection, or are you using a connection pool, if so the connection pool might be misbehaving with regard to resetting/cleaning up after a `close()` on the logical connection.

Comment: It's a fresh connection, I'm not using a connection pool.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have exactly the same problem. Open one connection, insert some data, commit, close. Then open another connection but inserted data is not visible. Then close and open another connection..... after some time (1 munte aprox) I can see inserted data. I have TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED. Same problem occurs when I try from psql.

Comment: Have you had any light on this issue? We are experimenting the same. Thread one inserts some data and commits it and thread two running another transaction query the data immediately after the thread one commits, and the result of the query is different millisecond apart. This seems to me a very dangerous thing and I do hope something is wrong with our setup.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior corresponds to the REPEATABLE READ isolation mode, see [SET TRANSACTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html):

> REPEATABLE READ
>   All statements of the current transaction can only see rows committed before the
>   first query or data-modification statement
>   was executed in this transaction.

Try `connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED)` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: All my connections have TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED isolation.