# PostgreSQL unable to see data after being committed in a different thread for a very short while

Tags: java, postgresql, multithreading, transactions, apache-camel

We have a Spring Boot micro-service based on Apache Camel consuming messages from a Kafka topic doing some complex mappings and saving it to a PostgreSQL database in a few tables.

Sometimes during Kafka patching part of our scheduled maintenance we noticed the same message can be delivered more than once at exactly the same time which is not something we are happy about.

To address this we created a `key_locking` table to block the threads processing duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS key_locking VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY;
```

The idea about this was that every single thread getting the same Kafka message will try to `INSERT` and immediately `DELETE` the key in this `key_locking` table and if able to will continue with processing otherwise it will block waiting for the "wining thread" to either commit or rollback it's transaction. If commit then the "winning thread" will already saved some data in the business tables. Once the commit is done the blocked thread will be able to go ahead with the blocked `INSERT` then `DELETE` the same key. After doing this will check the business table if data for this Kafka message has already been created and if so it will insert the duplicate message into an exception table.

```
private boolean checkDuplicateByLocking(String key) {
  try {
    log.info("Inserting key={} into key_locking table{}", key);
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO key_locking (key) VALUES (?)", key);
    log.info("Inserted key={} into key_locking", key);
    
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM key_locking WHERE key=?", key);
    log.info("Deleted key={} from key_locking", key);
    
    var duplicateCheckResultJdbc = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM some_table WHERE key = '%s'", key), Long.class) > 0;
    var duplicateCheckResult = eventExtRepository.findByHdrId(key).isPresent();
    log.info("Duplicate check result for jdbc template is = " + duplicateCheckResultJdbc);
    log.info("Duplicate check result for repository is = " + duplicateCheckResult);
    
    return duplicateCheckResultJdbc;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.info("Unable to lock key", e);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then we created an integration test injecting duplicates on purpose and observed the logs.

In most of the runs it works as expected. You can always see one of the threads being blocked in the logs at `Inserting key=xyz into key_locking table` with the the log entry `Inserted key=xyz into key_locking` always popping up in the logs after the "winning thread" puts in the logs `Finished processing message with key=xyz`. However, when it fails we can notice in the logs that `duplicateCheckResultJdbc` is `false` but `duplicateCheckResult` is `true` which makes absolutely no sense. Changing the jdbcTemplate and repository call order has the same effect. The distance in the logs between the two counters is one or two milliseconds.

My question is how this could be possible. Once the data is committed by the other thread it should be visible everywhere no matter what when under `READ_COMMITTED` transaction insolation level. But I cannot spot anything wrong in what we are doing.

**UPDATE:**
I admit the description of the issue we encounter is a bit complex. Regardless of the scenario that causes it the question is how is it possible to not see committed data in a thread immediately after it was committed by a different thread. My explanation above was just to give you an idea about how we reached that issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand your algorithm. Research where the transaction boundaries are. Anyway, why don't you solve the problem in the natural way, by creating a unique constraint that prevents duplicate messages from being inserted?

Comment: The unique constraint is already there. The issue is that part of the processing, as I said in my question, some other data is inserted/updated before getting there. When the unique constraint violation happens all those data changes have to be rollbacked but still the duplicate has to be committed into the exception table. In Apache Camel we achieved the rollback by using `setRollbackOnly onException()` part of the route and opening a new sub route marked `transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_NEW")` but it did not work. With this approach we tried to detect duplicates part of the top transaction

Comment: The algorithm is not that complex, but maybe the way I explained it is :-) Two threads are trying to insert the same primary key into the `key_locking` table. One succeeds while the other one is blocked. When the `winning thread` finishes and commits its data it takes a millisecond or two before the blocked thread can see that data. The Java code presented in the question is run by two threads at the same time and was presented to give an idea about how we reached the issue.

Comment: I still don't see the need for the `key_locking` table. Just do all your inserts in a single transaction, then they all get rolled back on a unique key violation. When that exception happens and the inserts are rolled back, write the row into the exception table.

Comment: If everything is rollbacked and the message is gone from Kafka, how do you get the chance to then insert into the exception table? I assume you are aware Kafka does not support XA (2PC) transactions

Comment: After the rollback, you start a new transaction that inserts into the exception table. Or you use a subtransaction by setting a savepoint, `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` in the event of a problem and insert into the exception table in the original transaction.

Comment: Suspending the current transaction and starting a new autonomous one was the very first that we tried. Maybe not used properly in the Camel context and we could not get it to work. Then we came to this locking solution. Anyway in the meantime we changed the design a bit so we solved the issue. However the question still stands up: why two consecutive queries to the database bring different results when nothing else than the external tread modified the data.

Comment: There is no autonomous transaction. The usual workaround is to use a second database connection.

Comment: it seems like others asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829933/postgresql-commited-data-not-visible
That post gave me some ideas to check for as we do use connections pool and have no way to control which transaction starts first. However, I still hope something is wrong with our setup, not being able to see committed data is a very dangerous thing.